# Application installed with root in centos needs to be run by non-root user

Tags: permissions, browser, centos

I have installed an Application called PowerMTA on a centos 7 server. But, That application needed to be run as non-root user named "sam". That application serves over http on port 8080. Now as the software is installed as a root user I can't open the url via my browser. It's showing:
"your cache administrator is root."

Please help me, so that I can access that application url via my browser.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And why does `sudo` fail to work?

Comment: Sudo is working perfectly. My problem is that My application is running as root so, it can't be accesed over http. I am trying to access it via http. I am suspecting that, I have mistaken on applying the correct permissions on the application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. Port 8080 was not allowed on my server firewall & my access ip was not configured in my application. So, The solution is:

1. I allowed port 8080 on my server firewall policies.
2. I allowed my ip address on my application configuration.